# Referring to Null value with ArcPy Expressions?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser, null

How do I refer to Null values in a field using an expression in Python?

I've tried using the following as well as = None and =Null but nothing has worked yet:

```
ScoreCondition = "Cond_Score(!"+Condition+"!)"
codeblock1 = """def Cond_Score(cond):
                if cond > 90:
                    return 1
                elif cond >= 71 and cond <= 90:
                    return 2
                elif cond >= 51 and cond <= 70:
                    return 3
                elif cond >= 20 and cond <= 50:
                    return 4
                elif cond < 20:
                    return 5
                elif cond is None:
                    return 1"""
```

Comment: One equals sign is for assigning values. To test for equality, use two of them: `==`

Comment: I've confirmed all three of the following work when using the Field Calculator. Could it be an error somewhere else? Does the code work for the other condition? if cond == None: return 1 if cond is None: return 2 if not cond: return 3

Comment: can't you just put an Else: for the last elif?

Comment: What kind of feature storage is your data? Not every data type *can* store a None or Null value. Shapefiles can't, numeric Null becomes 0 and string Null becomes '' (an empty string). In geodatabases (personal, file or enterprise) Null values can be stored (test with cond == None as @DanC said) **but** your implementation of ScoreCondition = "Cond_Score(!"+Condition+"!)" doesn't look quite right, can you show your line where you call Cond_Score in CalculateField_management, it's possible you may be parsing your numbers as strings.

Comment: Why is your code in *strings*?

Comment: @jpmc26 because it's a field calculator expression http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-field.htm

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is that in Python 2 `None` [is less than everything](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2214223).

```
>>> None < 20
True
>>> None < numpy.nan
True
>>> None < float('-inf')
True
>>> None < 'Everything'
True
```

Notes:

- In ArcGIS Pro (Python 3) you'll get a `TypeError` using a numeric comparison operator with `None` which will help avoid this issue.
- This doesn't apply to shapefiles as the old dBase format .dbf that stores the attribute table doesn't support null values

In your expression, Python is returning `True` when evaluating the 
 `elif cond < 20` clause when `cond` is really `None` so never gets to the `elif cond is None:` clause.

So the following will work because it tests for `None` first:

```
def Cond_Score(cond):
    if cond is None:
        return 1
    elif cond > 90:
        return 1
    elif cond >= 71 and cond <= 90:
        return 2
    elif cond >= 51 and cond <= 70:
        return 3
    elif cond >= 20 and cond <= 50:
        return 4
    elif cond < 20:
        return 5
```