# Modifying null values in ArcPy for ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, null

How can I say in ArcGIS Pro if the field (String) is Null, then replace it with "No"?

I was trying this:

```
database_field.replace("Null","No")
```

No error occurred, but the null values did not change...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Refer to a Null value with ArcPy Expressions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/308272/how-to-refer-to-a-null-value-with-arcpy-expressions)

Comment: Use Field Calculator. Look at the help section

Answer (score 1):

If you are working in a gdb file you can use these commands in a python window even without starting an edit session:

```
>>> with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor ("layer", 'database_field', 'database_field IS NULL') as uc:
...     for row in uc:
...         row[0] = 'No'
...         uc.updateRow (row)
...         
>>>
```